# Angular expression is not getting evaluated at run time. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I have the following problem.

I have an html code like this:

```
<ul class="board-list gutter js-board-list clearfix">

   <li class="" ng-repeat="board in boardsUserOwns.success.boards">
        <a class="js-open-board highlight-icon    unknown" ng-click="getBoardDetails('{{board[0]}}')" href="" style="  background-color: #0E74AF; ">
        <span class="thumbnail" style=" ; background-color: #0E74AF; "></span>
        <span class="fade"></span>
        <span class="board-list-item-name" title="Geneva">{{board[0]}}</span>
        </a>
   </li>
<ul>
```

The line:

```
<a class="js-open-board highlight-icon    unknown" ng-click="getBoardDetails('{{board[0]}}')" href="" style="  background-color: #0E74AF; ">
```

has an angular js expression `{{board[0]}}`.

When this page is loaded in the browser, I can see the above html like this in the console:

```
<a class="js-open-board highlight-icon    unknown" ng-click="getBoardDetails('userwithbelongsto1')" href="" style="  background-color: #0E74AF; ">
```

which works as expected.

The problem I find is, when I click on the `a` tag; In the controller I get the *not evaluated* angular code:

```
$scope.getBoardDetails = function(boardName)
{
   console.log("The board name is " + boardName)
}
```

the console prints:

```
 The board name is {{board[0]}}
```

I'm confused now, where I'm making mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the curly braces. Try `getBoardDetails(board[0])`

The reason you are seeing `{{board[0]}}` printed in the console, is because that string is what is sent to the function, as the boardName argument. As you have it, `getBoardDetails('{{board[0]}}')` is saying, calling this function with the string `{{board[0]}}`. But when the html is parsed, it is properly replacing that expression.

Comment: This works, but in angular we need to put the expression in `{{}}}` statement, to get parsed right?

Comment: Yes, if you want it in the template. The way that functions are bound and executed, is on the scope, therefore you don't need the {{ and }}, as it isn't in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I have to display individual boards onclick on of grid element in figure . I am getting borad_id from database , how to proceed next .
figure url :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Sn2.png

```js
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('board.boardDescription', {
      url: '/:bid',
      templateUrl:'js/main/templates/board.html'
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul class="board-list gutter js-board-list clearfix" >
                    <li ng-repeat="board in boardName">
                     <a ui-sref="board.boardDescription({bid:board._id})" class="js-open-board highlight-icon" style="background-color: #0066A1;">
                       <span class="details">
                          <span class="board-list-item-name">{{board.name}}</span>
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
```

![sample toodlist app figure ]